# If an integer n, greater

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If an integer $n$, greater than $8$, is a solution of the equation $x^2 -ax + b=0$ and the representation of a in base n is $18$, then what is the base $n$ representation of $b$?

I honestly am so lost I have no clue how to do this.

Comment: What have you tried? Show some effort or else this could possibly be downvoted/removed.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: I honestly am so lost. Sorry but I really am confused!

Comment: What does it mean that representation of $a$ in base $n$ is $18$?

Comment: I don't know. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are told that $a=18_n=n+8$, and that

$$0=n^2-an+b=n^2-(n+8)n+b.$$

Hence

$$b=8n=80_n.$$